# Struggling with promises and async functions in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm working on a React project where I have a function that fetches paginated data recursively. This function is defined in another function, where I activate the loading screen with `showLoading()` at the start, where I'm calling the fetching data function in the body and deactivate the loading screen with `hideLoading()` at the end. The function:

```
const fetchPlaylist = (playlistId) => {
    showLoading()
    const getPlaylistDataRecursively = (url) => {
      fetch('/spotify/get-track-ids', {headers: {
        'url': url
      }})
      .then(response => response.json())
      .then(data => {
        console.log(data)

        setTitles(data.title)
        setArtists(data.artist)
        setFeatures(data.features)
        setIds(data.track_ids)

        if (data.next_url) {
          const next_url = data.next_url.replace('https://api.spotify.com/v1', '')
          getPlaylistDataRecursively(next_url)
        }
      })
    }
    getPlaylistDataRecursively(`/playlists/${playlistId}/tracks/?offset=0&limit=100`)
    hideLoading()
  }
```

I believe I can attach a promise to the getPlaylistDataRecursively call with the `then` keyword but I'm getting a `TypeError: Cannot read property 'then' of undefined`. Probably because getPlaylistDataRecursively doesn't return anything. How do I make sure that `hideLoading` is called after getPlaylistDataRecursively is done?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You always need to `return` a promise.

```
const fetchPlaylist = (playlistId) => {
    showLoading()
    const getPlaylistDataRecursively = (url) => {
      return fetch('/spotify/get-track-ids', {headers: {
        'url': url
      }})
      .then(response => response.json())
      .then(data => {
        console.log(data)

        setTitles(data.title)
        setArtists(data.artist)
        setFeatures(data.features)
        setIds(data.track_ids)

        if (data.next_url) {
          const next_url = data.next_url.replace('https://api.spotify.com/v1', '')
          return getPlaylistDataRecursively(next_url)
        }
      })
    }
    return getPlaylistDataRecursively(`/playlists/${playlistId}/tracks/?offset=0&limit=100`)
      .then(() => hideLoading());
  }
```

Or, using async/await:

```
const fetchPlaylist = async (playlistId) => {
    showLoading()
    const getPlaylistDataRecursively = async (url) => {
      const response = await fetch('/spotify/get-track-ids', {headers: {
        'url': url
      }})
      const data = response.json()
      console.log(data)
      setTitles(data.title)
      setArtists(data.artist)
      setFeatures(data.features)
      setIds(data.track_ids)
      if (data.next_url) {
        const next_url = data.next_url.replace('https://api.spotify.com/v1', '')
        await getPlaylistDataRecursively(next_url)
      }
    }
    await getPlaylistDataRecursively(`/playlists/${playlistId}/tracks/?offset=0&limit=100`)
    hideLoading()
  }
```

Comment: would also add `await showLoading()`, anyhow great answer

Comment: Thanks, Hagai. Nothing in the question indicated that showLoading() or hideLoading() returned a promise. Often those kinds of methods are synchronous. But yes, if they are async, then they should be awaited.